Transaction failed and BONK token not transferred to Phantom wallet
I was transferring out BONK tokens from Binance to my Phantom wallet and unfortunately the transaction failed.
Transaction ID: 5om1zJpN5yoi4nJtiGZAvUf6QiifYeTLonvhvgqpraAgR4svqdf89XvEaRoFmAY75Rnk9AVmMyDkDhzPbtd4zNb6
There is an error: "Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed - Provided owner is not allowed"
Can anyone help to uncover what happened to these BONK tokens?

When a transaction fails, no transfer has occurred. I would consider BONK to be still at Binance.
